# Firefox hangs with Selenium hub using TestNG suite (org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: connection refused)

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid, testng-eclipse

I am developing a test suite which runs the test on different browser. First I am trying to make it work on firefox. But I am having issues with Selenium hub and TestNG. Firefox hangs and does not quit on its own. I am getting configuration error in TestNG. Please help.

```java
public class DIPTestConfigureDriver {
    // Declare ThreadLocal Driver (ThreadLocalMap) for ThreadSafe Tests
    protected static ThreadLocal<RemoteWebDriver> driver = new ThreadLocal<RemoteWebDriver>();
    protected String strUrl;
    protected String strExpectedTitle;

    @BeforeMethod
    @Parameters({ "browser", "url", "node", "expectedTitle" })
    public void setupTest(String browser, String url, String node, String expectedResult) throws MalformedURLException {

        // Set test url
        strUrl = url;

        // Set expected page title
        strExpectedTitle = expectedResult;

        // Set DesiredCapabilities
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

        // Set BrowserName
        capabilities.setCapability("browserName", browser);

        // Set Browser to ThreadLocalMap
        driver.set(new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(node), capabilities));
    }

    public WebDriver getDriver() {
        // Get driver from ThreadLocalMap
        return driver.get();
    }

    @AfterMethod(alwaysRun = true)
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        getDriver().quit();
    }

    @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
    void terminate() {
        // Remove the ThreadLocalMap element
        driver.remove();
    }
}
```

I installed firefox extended support release just now. It helped creating a session. But I am getting another error, org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: connection refused. Is it because my firewall is blocking the connection ?

Error :

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: connection refused
Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:33:15.31Z'
System info: host: '4DELTHUNDIYI', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_161'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
remote stacktrace: 
Command duration or timeout: 61.81 seconds
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 17:00:58'
System info: host: '4DELTHUNDIYI', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_161'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:249)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:158)
    at com.here.dip.test.DIPTestConfigureDriver.setupTest(DIPTestConfigureDriver.java:41)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:523)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:224)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:599)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:869)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1193)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:126)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: connection refused
Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:33:15.31Z'
System info: host: '4DELTHUNDIYI', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_161'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
remote stacktrace: 
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 17:00:58'
System info: host: '4DELTHUNDIYI', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_161'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$new$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:57)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$2(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:104)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:123)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:73)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.RemoteSession$Factory.performHandshake(RemoteSession.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSession$Factory.apply(ServicedSession.java:159)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ActiveSessionFactory.lambda$apply$12(ActiveSessionFactory.java:176)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$11$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ActiveSessionFactory.apply(ActiveSessionFactory.java:179)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.NewSessionPipeline.lambda$null$2(NewSessionPipeline.java:65)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Collections$2.tryAdvance(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.NewSessionPipeline.lambda$createNewSession$3(NewSessionPipeline.java:68)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.DistinctOps$1$2.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.Streams$StreamBuilderImpl.tryAdvance(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.tryAdvance(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.NewSessionPipeline.createNewSession(NewSessionPipeline.java:71)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.commandhandler.BeginSession.execute(BeginSession.java:65)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.WebDriverServlet.lambda$handle$1(WebDriverServlet.java:246)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include details about what configuration error you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks @KrishnanMahadevan. Done.

Comment: That doesn't look like the complete stacktrace. Please share the complete stacktrace

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan

Comment: Sorry, I am new to selenium hub. Added full trace. On chrome it is working fine after downloading chromedriver and adding environment variable. I downloaded firefox extended support release. should I also download firefox driver ?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has got nothing to do with TestNG. Your stacktrace indicates that the server component responsible for spawning your Firefox instance didn't start.

You mentioned in your comments that you are using a ESR version of Firefox but you didn't mention what version.

In either case, you should first download geckodriver (which is the server component for firefox), add its location to your PATH variable, restart your node and then try restarting your test again.

If the test fails once again, you would need to look at the console of the node (the command prompt wherein you started the node) to find out what is the error is.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using geckodriver for running your tests on FF?
Does your URL include the port the hub using? 
Did you use set system property? see bellow.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "path to driver\\geckodriver.exe");
```